# C++ Platform Support

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, macros

I am planning to make my C++ application compatible with Windows/Mac/Linux. At the moment I came up with this "code":

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
   #include <Windows.h>
#elif defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
   #include <TargetConditionals.h>
   #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 1
       #error "IOS simulator is not supported!"
   #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 1
       #error "IOS is not supported!"
   #elif TARGET_OS_MAC == 1
       //MAC??????
   #else
       #error "Unknown Apple platform!"
#endif

#else
   #error "The platform you are currently using is not compatible!"
#endif
```

I don't know if I implemented Windows correctly, but at least I know what to include. So my questions are:

- What do I need to import to use the Mac system library?
- How can I implement linux support and what do i need to include to use his library?

I need the system libraries because later I planned to make a window class based on the system's libraries, I think you can do it for Windows but I am not really if you can do it sure on linux/mac.

Update #1:
Ok so I figured out which macros to use but what libraries should I include?

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__CYGWIN32__)
#define PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#include <Windows.h>

#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 1
#define PLATFORM_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#error "Iphone simulator environment is not compatible!"
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 1
#define PLATFORM_IPHONE
#error "Iphone environment is not compatible!"
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC == 1
#define PLATFORM_MACOS
//what do I need to include here???
#endif
#elif defined(__ANDROID__)
#define PLATFORM_ANDROID
#error "Android environment is not compatible!"
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__linux) || defined(linux)
#define PLATFORM_LINUX
//what do i need to include here???
#else
#error "The platform you are currently using is not compatible!"
#endif
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190702094426/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system
It’s an old but still highly useful list of the OS specific macros.

Comment: actually: noone can realy answer this as this depends on what your particular program need.  you need to include, what you want to use and nothing else. if you don't intend to use something, no need to include anything. noone can guess what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: oh, i thought there was a library like Windows.h for each system. Anyway where can i find some decumentation about mac/linux libraries?

Comment: Whats so difficult in telling what you want to achieve and you need a libraries for(and no windows.h is usually not sufficiant for a win32 application)

More information:
https://www.gtk.org/
https://www.qt.io/
https://www.kernel.org/